# Join on Multiple columns with duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables Master table and the Matched Master Table based on the same saldate , saltime , lctid ,masid the counts has to be pulled up

For count(masid,saldate,saltime,lctid)>1 , for masid 121 in master table there are 5 records in Master Matched 3 records, I need to get the output which are not in Mactched and how much in Master and the total amount with the masid

```
        Master          
ID  Saldate   SalTime   lctid   masid   Sal_amt
101  1/1/2000   100    120      121      15
102  1/1/2000   100    120      121      25
103  1/1/2000   100    120      121     100
118  1/1/2001   120    118      201      25
119  1/1/2009   302    222      187      60
104  1/1/2000   100    120      121     125
108  1/1/2000   100    120      121      22

    Master matched              
ID  Saldate     SalTime lctid   masid   Sal_Amt
101 1/1/2000    100     120     121      15
102 1/1/2000    100     120     121     25
118 1/1/2001    120     118     201     25
119 1/1/2009    302     222     187     60
```

> ```
>     OP1-Master                            OP2-Master matched  
> Masid Count(iD)   SalAMt          Masid    Count(iD) Sal_Amt
> 121        3       247            121          2     40
> ```

Comment: I tried the joins no correct answers, cross join could give but taking a lot of time

Comment: Post your query.